# get some Data by GET method(REST)

Tags: node.js, json, npm, postman, nodemon

I have a json file and I want to get only some data like if i have name, roll no, address, mob number. I want to print/show only roll no and address. How to do it in node.js? Please tell

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, share you tried so far and what problems you encounter and we all will be glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have a JSON file you would just remove the fields you don't want to use then send the reminder to the client. You can do this using the filter method.

```
JsonData.filter((item)=>//Remove the unwanted items e.g item.name&&item.mobnumber)
```

This won't permanently remove the items but just filter out the items that you want to ignore.

Comment: Thank you Problem is solved. I use .filter method